# Properties of this rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've forgotten a lot of basic linear algebra so I was hoping someone might be able to provide a few properties of this matrix.

$$\mathbf b \mathbf a^\top = \begin{pmatrix} a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 & a_3b_1 & \cdots & a_nb_1 \\ a_1b_2 & a_2b_2 & a_3b_2 & \cdots & a_nb_2 \\ a_1b_3 & a_2b_3 & a_3b_3 & \cdots & a_nb_3 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_1b_n & a_2b_n & a_3b_n & \cdots & a_nb_n \end{pmatrix}$$

I know the determinant is $0$ and the rank is $1$, so the nullity must be $n-1$. Are there any other properties this matrix has?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, the row $i$ and column $j$ entry is $b_ia_j$, so the matrix equals $\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T$, where $\mathbf{a} = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}$. Maybe you can search online for something like "properties of matrices of the form $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T$" to find out more about them (e.g. their eigenvalues and eigenvectors).

Comment: For example, see [Properties of the matrix 
$A=uv^T$, where $u,v∈\Bbb{R}^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253593/properties-of-the-matrix-a-uvt-where-u-v-in-mathbb-rm) or [Finding orthogonal projectors onto the range/null space of the matrix A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686223/finding-orthogonal-projectors-onto-the-range-null-space-of-the-matrix-a).

Comment: Also look up “outer product.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: $det(I + ba^T) = 1 + a^Tb$